# Ckeditor - RichTextField in Template doesn't work - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-ckeditor

I am trying to display the RichTextField in a Django Template. In the Admin Panel it works but not in the template.
My Template called create.html:

```
{% block main %}
    <div class="blocker" style="height: 100px;"></div>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Absenden</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Forms.py:

```
class Create(forms.ModelForm):
    content = RichTextField()
    title = forms.CharField(label='title', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']
```

Views.py

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Create(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            Post(title=title, content=content).save()
            return redirect("../blog")
    else:
        form = Create()
    return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': form})
```

I tried different things in the forms.

Comment: Can you also share your `Post` model since `RichTextField` is a model field not a form field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that you have already installed the package using `pip install django-ckeditor` and also included it in `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your `settings.py` file.

Try to use `{{ form.media }}` tag which include the necessary scripts and stylesheets, so in the template:

```html
{% block main %}
    <div class="blocker" style="height: 100px;"></div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {{ form.media }}
        <button type="submit">Absenden</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

In your `forms.py`, import the [`CKEditorWidget`](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#widget)
and use it to override the default widget for the content field, like so:

```py
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget

class Create(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    title = forms.CharField(label='title', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']
```